# How does copy work in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, copy-paste

I've noticed that there seems to be **potentially** three pastes:

> 1) The default Right click -> paste
>
> 2) SHIFT + INSERT
>
> 3) Highlight and middle mouse click

But how do they work? I tried Right click and copying a `git clone` command from bitbucket but when I use `SHIFT + INSERT` it pastes a newline, right clicking and clicking paste then copies the command successfully. Are they all separate from one another or is there a way I can link them all up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more than one clipboard in X11, called *selections*. One is PRIMARY and the other one is CLIPBOARD.

- The PRIMARY selection is updated as soon as you highlight text. It is used for middle-click, and usually for Shift+Insert.
- The CLIPBOARD selection is, like the traditional Windows clipboard, updated when you use "Cut/Copy" menu items or Ctrl+X/Ctrl+C, and pasted when you use the "Paste" menu item or Ctrl+V.

(In some programs, like web browsers, Shift+Insert actually pastes from CLIPBOARD.)

You can merge them with [autocutsel](http://www.nongnu.org/autocutsel/).

Comment: ah I see! Thank you, I did feel like they were separate but didn't really know about it. So thanks for clearing up confusion :)